# httpd.conf, change to disable auth

Tags: authentication, root, apache

How might I go about modifying this part of my httpd.conf, so that I can gain access to this even though I have lost my password.

```
AliasMatch ^/mydisk/(.*) "/links/webdav/$1"
    <Directory "/links/webdav">
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        DAV On
        #deprecated in httpd-2.0 DAVParam Hide Email;.htaccess
        AllowOverride None
        AuthName "mydisk"
        AuthType Basic
        require valid-user
        AuthSQLiteGroupTable /dev/null
        AuthSQLiteGroupField /dev/null
        AuthSQLiteDB /var/lib/sqlite/registration
        AuthSQLiteUserTable users
        AuthSQLiteNameField LoginID
        AuthSQLitePasswordField Crypt
    #    IndexIgnore Maildir .htaccess
        Satisfy all
</Directory>
```

When I try to access it on my server from the browser I don't know the login credentials. I have full root access to the server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's using SQLite for the authentication... you should be able to do the following in the commandline:

```
$ sqlite3 /var/lib/sqlite/registration
sqlite> SELECT LoginID, Crypt FROM users;
```

And that should show you what the username and passwords are.

You could completely disable authentication, but since it's DAV, it could potentially mean anyone could write to it.

Comment: I checked the SQLite database and the only username/password in there is mine and those of my users (which I created). So, the question is, why am I unable to Authenticate with it?

Comment: has it worked in the past? or is it something you are trying to set up?